# How to authenticate websites from firefox addon?

Tags: firefox, authentication, firefox-addon

I'm developing a firefox addon for the first time, and I want the user to be able to log in with twitch, facebook etc. I know that I have to do the 'Implicit Grant Flow' as described here:
[Twitch-API/authentication](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/authentication.md)

So what I first do is to open a new window with the url

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/authorize
?response_type=token
&client_id=[your client ID]
&redirect_uri=[your registered redirect URI]
&scope=[space separated list of scopes]
```

After the user enters name and password he gets redirected to

```
http://[your registered redirect URI]/#access_token=[an access token]
```

Now the question is, how do I get the access token? As far as I know, I can't access the url of a child window if it has entered another domain. I searched the whole internet for a solution to how to authenticate websites via addons but I found nothing. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a page-mod to inject a script into a page that matches the pattern:

`http://[your registered redirect URI]/**#**access_token` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod

You can have that `page-mod` send a message back to your `main.js` or `index.js` of what the tokens are by having it send `window.location.hash`

Or you can handle it yourself. This is the way I like to do it. I create a `<xul:browser>` element and let the user interact with that. This is a low level method not readily available to SDK addons. However if you want to see it in action you can try it in my addon here - version 1.6 - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nativeshot/versions/